# jQuery How to Use radio button to control radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
$(function() {
  $("#aa").click(function() {
    $("#aa2").attr("checked", true);
  });
  $("#bb").click(function() {
    $("#bb2").attr("checked", true);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='radio' name='a' id='aa'/>aa
<input type='radio' name='a' id='bb'/>bb
<br>
<input type='radio' name='b' id='aa2'/>aa2
<input type='radio' name='b' id='bb2/'>bb2
```

When I click aa, aa2 checked, click bb, bb2 cheked. However, then click aa, bb2 remains checked, and aa2 is not checked

Answer (score 1):

You likely need to use the `.prop()` method instead of the `.attr()` method.

When using `.attr()`, you are setting an attribute. When the attribute is set, the property will be set. In your case, if the attribute has already been set, it will not change the property again, therefore you should just change the property using `.prop()` to begin with.

As a side note, I'd suggest listening to the `change` event of the radio elements rather than the `click` event.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/3zdwq6h0/)

```
$("#aa").on('change', function () {
    $("#aa2").prop("checked", "checked");
});
$("#bb").on('change', function () {
    $("#bb2").prop("checked", "checked");
});
```

See [`.prop()` vs `.attr()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr).

Comment: Could shrink it down even further to `$("input[name='a']").on('change', function () {
    $("input[name='b']").eq($(this).index()).prop("checked", "checked");
});`

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you

```js
$(function() {
  $("input[name=a]").change(function() {
    $("input[name=b]").removeAttr('checked');
    $("input[name=b]").filter('[value='+$(this).val()+']').attr('checked', true);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='radio' name='a' value="1" />aa
<input type='radio' name='a' value="2" />bb
<br>
<input type='radio' name='b' value="1" />aa2
<input type='radio' name='b' value="2" />bb2
```